# How to I parse custom tags this string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse a string which contains custom tags like `[link][description][link-url][/link]` and I want to convert it to `<a href="link-url">description</a>`. 
Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link)?

Comment: looks promising let me evaluate that

Comment: Even if you're only interested in their link syntax, you could reference the code to parse it.

Comment: This is definitely a very good long term solution but for now as a quick fix I will go with @JustinPihony's answer. But I will for sure look at Markdown and may be integrate it later in my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the regex you could use:

```
\[link\]\[(.*)\]\[(.*)\]\[\/link\]
```

Then you can use the regex replace:

```
<a href="$2">$1</a>
```

Comment: :) it worked like a charm except that I need to reverse $2 and $1 <a href="$2">$1</a>